# Google Places API PlaceFilter

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using Google Places API for Android and am trying to limit the results to only show Restaurants.  I have included a PlaceFilter and seems to be correct but doesn't seem to be applying the filter and giving other results aside from Restaurants.  See code:

```
ArrayList<String> restrictToRestaurants = new ArrayList<>();
                restrictToRestaurants.add(Integer.toString(Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT));
                PlaceFilter pf;
                pf = new PlaceFilter(false, restrictToRestaurants);

                PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, pf);
                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                        for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {

                            placeLikelihood.getPlace().getPlaceTypes();

                            Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' with " + "likelihood: %g", placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(), placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                        }
                        likelyPlaces.release();
                    }
                });
```

Anyone have any ideas how to apply the PlaceFilter?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the only ways to filter the results of `getCurrentPlace` are outlined in the [PlaceFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceFilter.html) class:

> **requireOpenNow**    if true, return only places open now
>
> **restrictToPlaceIds**    the specific PlaceIds to match

Each one of those PlaceIds is supposed to match to a specific location. Unfortunately, it looks like filtering the results of `Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace` by the type of place (eg restaurants) is not supported yet. The `Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT` you referenced can be used in [AutocompleteFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.html) for `GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions`.

Comment: Thanks.  After reading about the API a bit more carefully I don't think it's what I should it should be.  Sounds more like it will grab the places the device was actually in.  I was under the impression that Locations services would just grab places around you.  The name is quite deceiving in my opinion.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help you or not, but the API does expose a widget that can be used to view nearby places. It allows the user to pick one of those places and returns the result to you. That might not fit what you are trying to accomplish though. Also, it doesn't seem like you can filter it by place types. 

https://developers.google.com/places/android/placepicker

Comment: It is still not fixed. It has taken a whole day along and i got this post on stackoverflow. Wondering developers are not keen in using android feature or I am doing wrongly. Kindly reply if it is fixed or there is any other way to work other than AutoCompleteFilter.

Comment: I have opened a bug on google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230781&thanks=230781&ts=1482334589. Kindly star the issue to get tuned about the bug.

Comment: This isn't really a bug, it's just the way the API is designed. The documentation is a bit confusing if you don't know what an "ID" is, but suffice to say that each ID maps to exactly one place in Google's database of places. This is different from a "type" (eg restaurant or hospital). Knowing this, if you read the documentation you will see that it works exactly as it says that it does.