# Using PlaceFilter with PlaceDetection.getCurrentPlace

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I was attempting to use the Google Play Services Places API to programmatically retrieve restaurants being visited by a user.  There is no documented way to filter based on categories in the current API, so I used a Places web service call to retrieve the restaurants near my current location. The PlaceFilter appears to function properly when used to filter the results in the loop below, but it doesn't have any effect when used in the `Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mClient, filter)` call.  Is there something that I'm missing?

```
@Override
public Observable<Location> getCurrentLocation(String categories) {

    ArrayList<String> placeSet = new ArrayList<String>();
    NearbySearchResponse response = null;

    Observable<NearbySearchResponse> responseObservable = mGooglePlacesEndpoint.nearbySearchObservable(MAPS_API_KEY, "30.485277,-97.678878", 200, categories);

    // Perform a Places API query on the returned results of the filtered WS call

    return responseObservable
            .flatMap(RESPONSE_LOCATION_FUNC)
            .flatMap(LOCATION_ID_FUNC)
            .take(10) // API docs indicate a limit of 10 IDs
            .toList()
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<String>, Observable<Location>>() {

                @Override
                public Observable<Location> call(List<String> placeIds) {
                    final PlaceFilter filter = new PlaceFilter(true, placeIds);
                    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Location> subscriber) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "filter: " + StringUtils.join(filter.getPlaceIds(), "|"));
                            PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mClient, filter);

                            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer placeLikelihoods) {
                                    for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : placeLikelihoods) {
                                        Place place = placeLikelihood.getPlace();
                                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed() /*&& filter.matches(place)*/) // this filter.matches(place) is a work-around for a google bug
                                            subscriber.onNext(new GooglePlacesLocation(place, placeLikelihood.getLikelihood(), placeLikelihoods.getAttributions()));
                                    }
                                    Status status = placeLikelihoods.getStatus();
                                    if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                                        // @TODO propagate this error somehow
                                        // subscriber.onError();
                                    }
                                    placeLikelihoods.release();
                                    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed())
                                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Looks like the web API is what you should go with.  Someone asked this exact question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358460/google-places-api-placefilter

Comment: They were trying to do something that the documentation didn't actually say you can do in that post.  I was trying to do what, according to the documentation, should be working.  Maybe it's time to report a bug to Google.  There is an undocumented constructor to PlaceFilter that allows place type restrictions, but that also fails to work.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Interesting.  I'll give your code a try when I have time.

Comment: You are right on, this is a bug in our API. Sincere apologies for the inconvenience. We hope to have this fixed in the next Google Play Services release!

Comment: I have opened the ticket on google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230781&thanks=230781&ts=1482334589 -- Please star the ticket to get feedback.